# Endpoint aceitar objeto e array de objetos

Tags: api, microsserviços, arquitetura-computadores

Essa é uma dúvida que se refere mais às boas práticas.

O cenário é que tenho 2 endpoints para receber um dado registro. 
No primeiro recebo o objeto e cadastro um por requisição.
No segundo recebo um array deste objeto, itero e cadastro um por vez.

Minha dúvida é se há uma convenção sobre se eu deveria unir estes dois endpoints ou continuar oferecendo um serviço para cadastro em conjunto e outro individual.

Comment: A não ser que haja um motivo muito forte para você ter esses 2 endpoints separados, por que não simplesmente oferecer o de cadastro múltiplo? Penso que nem é tanto seguir ou não alguma convenção, mas facilitar a manutenção do seu código, evitar duplicidade de código (acredito que você tenha métodos separados, e quase iguais, pra tratar cada endpoint) e o potencial surgimento de bugs caso tenha que atualizar essa lógica.